# How to do a complex wide-to-long operation for network analysis

Tags: r

I have survey data that includes who the respondent is (iAmX), who they work with (withX), how frequently they work with each partner (freqX), and how satisfied they are with each partner (likeX). Participants can select multiple options for who they are and who they work with.

I would like to go from something like this, with one row per respondent:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='
 id iAmA  iAmB  iAmC  withA withB withC freqA freqB freqC likeA likeB likeC
  1 X X NA  X X NA  3 2 NA  3 2 NA
  2 NA  NA  X X NA  NA  5 NA  NA  5 NA  NA  
                 ')
```

To something like this, with one row per combination, where "from" is who the actor is and "to" is who they work with:

```
goal <- read.table(header=T, text='
               id from  to  freq  like
              1 A A 3 3
              1 B A 3 3
              1 A B 2 2
              1 B B 2 2
              2 C A 5 5
               ')
```

I have tried some melt, gather, and reshape functions but frankly I think I'm just not up to the logic puzzle today. I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Interesting problem but I am somewhat stumped how `iAmX` and `withX` relates to `from` and `to`. Does `X`, i.e., `A`, `B`, `C` refer to the same person?

Comment: Sorry, unclear on my part. The goal is to take the survey data, which asks which actor(s) they are and who they work with, to individual interactions. "I Am" stuff becomes "from", and "with" becomes "to." I could have written that better.

Answer (score 1):

Although I must admit I have not fully understood OP's logic, the code below reproduces the expected `goal`.

The key points here are [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s incarnation of the `melt()` function which is able to reshape multiple measure columns simultaneously and the cross join function `CJ()`.

```
library(data.table)
# reshape multiple measure columns simultaneously
cols <- c("iAm", "with", "freq", "like")
long <- melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = patterns(cols), 
             value.name = cols, variable.name = "to")[
               # rename factor levels
               , to := forcats::fct_relabel(to, function(x) LETTERS[as.integer(x)])]
# create combinations for each id
combi <- long[, CJ(from = na.omit(to[iAm == "X"]), to = na.omit(to[with == "X"])), by = id]
# join to append freq and like
result <- combi[long, on = .(id, to), nomatch = 0L][, -c("iAm", "with")]
# reorder result
setorder(result, id)
result
```

> ```
>    id from to freq like
> 1:  1    A  A    3    3
> 2:  1    B  A    3    3
> 3:  1    A  B    2    2
> 4:  1    B  B    2    2
> 5:  2    C  A    5    5
> ```

---

The intermediate results are

```
long
```

> ```
>    id to  iAm with freq like
> 1:  1  A    X    X    3    3
> 2:  2  A <NA>    X    5    5
> 3:  1  B    X    X    2    2
> 4:  2  B <NA> <NA>   NA   NA
> 5:  1  C <NA> <NA>   NA   NA
> 6:  2  C    X <NA>   NA   NA
> ```

and

```
combi
```

> ```
>    id from to
> 1:  1    A  A
> 2:  1    A  B
> 3:  1    B  A
> 4:  1    B  B
> 5:  2    C  A
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Sorry my logic wasn't completely clear, but this helps a lot.